# How to hock commits (on JIRA 7.0.5 with DVCS connected to Bitbucket Cloud)

Tags: git, jira, bitbucket, commit, dvcs

I have JIRA 7.0.5 + DVCS (Latest) connected to Bitbucket Cloud.

In JIRA: repo enabled, smart commits are on, branches creating successful.

But I see no activity about my new commits. What I need to do?

Comment: Done. Need to use "commit message" when commiting :)

Answer (score 0):

Need to use "commit message" when commiting :)

Example: JRA-123 #time 2d 5h

Reference: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/processing-jira-software-issues-with-smart-commit-messages-298979931.html

Comment: Note that you do not need to include a smart commit command eg #time , for it to show up in JIRA. Just having the JIRA issue key in the commit message will be enough.